# Question regarding parametric surfaces

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametrization

Suppose that **r**$_0(s)$, $s\in[0,L]$ is a smooth parametric curve contained in a plane $\pi$, where $s$ is the is the arc-length parameter. What is the area of the surface with parametric equations **r**$(s,u)=\ $**r**$_0s+u$**n**; $0≤s≤L, \ 0≤u≤s$, where **n** is a unit normal vector of the plane $\pi$?

Comment: What are your thoughts/where are you running into trouble?

Comment: This question is quite abstract. Can you figure out what to do in the specific case where the curve is a circle in the xy-plane